# Accuracy does not increase Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm currently working on a project using Pytorch. I want to evaluate the accuracy of a neural network but it seems it does not increase when the test is running. The output I get is:

[image: Output of the script]

As you can see, I print the accuracy of every epoch always getting the same number.

Here you are the code of my classifier:

```
class Classifier(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=6, out_features=2, bias=True)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=1, bias=True)
        self.activation = torch.sigmoid

    def forward(self, x):
        x=self.activation(self.layer1(x))
        x=self.activation(self.layer2(x))
        return x

model=Classifier()

def setParameters(m):
  if type(m) == torch.nn.Linear:
      torch.nn.init.uniform_(m.weight.data, -0.3, 0.3)
      torch.nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 1)

model.apply(setParameters)
model.layer1.bias.requires_grad = False
model.layer2.bias.requires_grad = False
```

The code I use to train the network is the following:

```
from google.colab import drive
import torch
import random

drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd drive/MyDrive/deeplearning/ass1/data

numbers = []
results = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  random.shuffle(lines)
  for line in lines:
    digitsOfNumber = [int(x) for x in str(line[0:6])]
    resultInteger = int(line[7:8])
    numbers.append(digitsOfNumber)
    results.append(resultInteger)

numbersTensor = torch.Tensor(numbers)
resultsTensor = torch.tensor(results)

dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(numbersTensor, resultsTensor)

trainsetSize = int((80/100) * len(dataset))

trainset, testset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [trainsetSize, len(dataset) - trainsetSize])
print(len(trainset), len(testset))
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=len(testset), shuffle=False)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=len(trainset), shuffle=False)

def get_accuracy(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        correct=0
        for x, y in iter(dataloader):
            out=model(x)
            correct+=(torch.argmax(out, axis=1)==y).sum()
        return correct/len(dataloader.dataset)

epochs=1425
losses=[]
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("Test accuracy: ", get_accuracy(model, testloader).item())
    model.train()
    print("Epoch: ", epoch)
    for x, y in iter(trainloader):
        out=model(x)
        l=loss(out, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        l.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        losses.append(l.item())
print("Final accuracy: ", get_accuracy(model, testloader))

for name, param in model.named_parameters():
  print(name, param)
```

The last part is the one I use to print out the accuracy and to train the network accordingly. How can I fix my issue?

Thank you in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: Does you loss function converge?

Answer (score -1):

The last layer of your model produces a tensor of shape `(batch size, 1)`, since you have set `out_features = 1`. I assume your dataset has more than 1 class?

When you are calculating your accuracy, `torch.argmax(out, axis=1)` will always give the same class index, being 0 in this case. This explains why your accuracy is constant.

I advise looking into your dataset and finding out how many classes you have, and modify your model based on that. If you have 10 classes, the last layer should have 10 output features based on how the rest of your code is set up.

Comment: My dataset has just 2 classes, that's why I have just an output. Isn't it enough?

Comment: Yes, with two classes you can use one output node. Then you have a binary classifier and will need to change your code accordingly. There are many great resources on the net on binary classifiers using neural networks in PyTorch.